# Nested lazy for-comprehension

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, for-comprehension

I have a deeply "nested" for-comprehension, simplified to 3 levels below: x, y, and z. I was hoping making only x a `Stream` would make the y and z computations lazy too:

```
val stream = for {
  x <- List(1, 2, 3).toStream
  y <- List("foo", "bar", "baz")
  z = {
    println("Processed " + x + y)
    x + y
  }
} yield z

stream take (2) foreach (doSomething)
```

But this computes all 3 elements, as evidenced by the 3 prints. I'd like to only compute the first 2, since those are all I take from the stream. I can work around this by calling `toStream` on the second `List` and so on. Is there a better way than calling that at every level of the for-comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it prints is:

```
Processed 1foo
Processed 1bar
Processed 1baz
stream: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[String] = Stream(1foo, ?)

scala> stream take (2) foreach (println)
1foo
1bar
```

The head of a `Stream` is always strictly evaluated, which is why you see `Processed 1foo` etc and not `Processed 2foo` etc. This is printed when you create the Stream, or more precisely, when the head of `stream` is evaluated.

You are correct that if you only wish to process each resulting element one by one then all the generators will have to be Streams. You could get around calling `toStream` by making them Streams to start with as in example below.

`stream` is a `Stream[String]` and its head needs to be evaluated. If you don't want to calculate a value eagerly, you could either prepend a dummy value, or better, make your value `stream` **`lazy`**:

```
lazy val stream = for {
  x <- Stream(1, 2, 3)
  y <- Stream("foo", "bar", "baz")
  z = { println("Processed " + x + y); x + y }
} yield z
```

This does not do any "processing" until you take each value:

```
scala> stream take 2 foreach println
Processed 1foo
1foo
Processed 1bar
1bar
```

Comment: Clarified my question. I didn't intend z to be `Unit`. Now there are 3 prints up-front, even though I only take the first 2 elements of the stream and `doSomething` with them. How do I make the 3rd print ("calculation") not happen?

Comment: @Bluu the three calculations are for each element of `y`, as should be clear from the "1" number. Like I said, the head is always evalulated. Try `stream take 4 foreach println` and you will see that the second batch are only calculated after the first 3 are taken

Comment: I see now. Thanks. And to only strictly evaluate the head _of the head_, that's why I need to call `List("foo", "bar", "baz").toStream`. Do you know any way around that?